# How to delete the duplicate data in table (Postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates

I want to delete the duplicated data in a table , I know there is a way use

```
SELECT
    fruit,
    COUNT( fruit )
FROM
    basket
GROUP BY
    fruit
HAVING
    COUNT( fruit )> 1
ORDER BY
    fruit;
```

to find them , buy I need to determine every column's value is equal , which means `tableA.* = tableA.*` (except `id` , id is the auto-increment primary key )

and I tried this:

```
SELECT
    *,
    COUNT( * )
FROM
    myTable
GROUP BY
    *
HAVING
    COUNT( * )> 1
ORDER BY
    id;
```

but it says I can't use `GROUP BY *` , so how can I find & delete the duplicated data(need every column's value is equal except id)?

Answer (score 0):

using

```
SELECT * DISTINCT
```

`DISTINCT` remove duplicated result

Comment: @choi GOD * will include Id column as well. So, it will not work.

Comment: If at all it has to be `select distinct * from ...` but that makes no sense at all, as that will include the primary key column and thus no duplicates will be  returned to begin with

Answer (score 0):

You need to try something similar to be below query. You apply `PARTITION BY` for the columns other than Id (as it is incrementing unique value). `PARTITION BY` should be applied for columns, for which you want to check duplicates. 
Also refer to [Row_Number in Postgres](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-row_number/) & [Common Table expression in Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html)

```
WITH DuplicateTableRows AS
(
SELECT Id, Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2... ORDER BY Id)
FROM 
Table1
)
DELETE FROM Table1
WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id FROM Table1 WHERE row_number > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using JSON:

```
select (to_jsonb(b) - 'id')
from basket b
group by 1
having count(*) > 1;
```

The result is as JSON.  Unfortunately, to extract the values back into a record, you need to list the columns individually.